# Ubuntu GRUB not showing up

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, windows

I installed Windows 10 on my laptop and after that I installed Ubuntu 20.04, but the grub menu isn't showing up, it still directly loads Windows 10.

I created new partitions for Ubuntu; I think that is the reason.

My SSD partitions

[image: screenshot of partitions]

I've tried this command but Windows 10 still boots and there's no sign of the GRUB menu.

```
bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

Answer (score 2):

One handy tool that every Linux user needs is a boot-repair tool on a bootable USB thumb drive. This will save you hours of trouble. I made mine using instructions [here](https://gparted.org/liveusb.php)
It will help you out of all manner of troubles, like what you have described.

Best of luck to you, and feel free to ask questions about this if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

1. When booting press `F2` to access firmware settings.
2. Find boot sequence.
3. Make sure Ubuntu is 1st and Windows boot manager is 2nd.
4. Save and exit (`F10`).

Alternatively if you use windows more than Ubuntu, you can access ubuntu from boot options by pressing `F12` during boot.

Comment: My HP g2 doesn't show up the Ubuntu in the bios boot sequence, it only shows OS Boot Manager, USB and the CD Rom boot options. Thanks

Comment: @ZHR I think I know what happened. Do you remember whether you could see Install alongside Windows option during Ubuntu installation? I get the feeling you didn't. The problem seems to be your boot mode. In firmware settings can you tell me what your boot mode is?

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to make sure you have [disabled fast startup](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/144870-1909-fast-startup-setting-gone-but-why-would-ms-enable-default.html) within Windows 10. If left enabled, this will lock your Windows partition, and installing the GRUB boot loader will silently fail.

Then, as @[Sasuke Uchiha](https://askubuntu.com/users/1073514/sasuke-uchiha) suggested, check whether you're booting in UEFI mode or BIOS mode (sometimes called "legacy" or "CSM" mode). If you're on UEFI mode, most likely you also have [Secure Boot enabled](https://www.howtogeek.com/283803/how-to-check-if-secure-boot-is-enabled-on-your-pc/), which is the default in newer laptops.

[Ubuntu has support for Secure Boot](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot) since version 16.04 IIRC; you just need to make sure you're booting the Ubuntu installer in UEFI mode instead of BIOS mode. Here's a good way to check from within the Ubuntu installer: if you turned on the option to "install third-party software" and was prompted to set a password, then you *definitely* have Secure Boot enabled and the installer is in UEFI mode. For more details, see [this wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) page.